# Hide to create a new record in many2one or many2many

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am working with res.partner object in customer form view in sale module
category_id use many2many field in customer form view. 
Based on the user I have to hide the create new category record in ODOO or OpenERP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using `options` attribute.
Check this example:

```
<record id="view_customer_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">view.customer.form.inherit</field>
  <field name="model">res.partner</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name='category_id' position='attributes'>
      <attribute name='options'>
        {"no_create": 1, "no_create_edit": 1}
      </attribute>
    </field> 
  </field>
</record>
```

> I know it is too late to answer but I hope it'll be helpful

.

Comment: Finally Good thanks Kenly Your answer it will helpful me in my future work